# Connecting delegate classes in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, interface-builder

I've got two controls in my Interface Builder file, and each of those controls I've created a separate delegate class for in code (Control1Delegate and Control2Delegate). I created two "Objects" in interface builder, made them of that type, and connected the controls to them as delegates. The delegates work just fine. My problem is, I need to share information from one delegate to the other delegate, and I'm not sure how.

What is the best way to do this? Combine the two delegates into one class, or somehow access a third class that they can both read? Since I'm not actually initializing the class anywhere in my code, I'm not sure how to get a reference to the actual instance of it (if there is an actual instance of it), or even access the "main" class that the project came with.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add outlets from either delegate to the other delegate. There are two ways to add an outlet to an object in IB (assuming you're using Xcode/IB version 3.0 or later:

1. If you have not generated the code for your delegate classes yet, select the desired delegate, then open the "Object Identity" tab in the IB inspector. Add a "Class outlet" of type NSObject. You should then be able to set this new outlet to the other delegate. Of course you will have to generate the code for your delegate class and add the generated source files to your Xcode project before you can load the nib.
2. If you've already generated the code for the delegate class (or added an NSObject to your NIB and set its Class to an existing class in your Xcode project), add an instance variable to the delegate class:

   `IBOutlet id outletToOtherDelegate;`

   As long as your Xcode project is open (as indicated by the green bubble in the lower-left of your NIB window), IB will automatically detect the new outlet and allow you to assign it to the other delegate object in your NIB.

Cocoa automatically connects these outlets at NIB load time. Once `awakeFromNib` is called on instances of your delegate objects, you may assume that all the other objects in the NIB have been instantiated and all outlets have been connected. You should not assume an order on calls to `awakeFromNib`, however.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can create outlets on each one and cross-bind them so that they each have the same data all the time.  If there's one model object they need to share, that's pretty tidy.  I don't actually know how to do this; I think I saw it in an iPhone tutorial one time!

Answer (score 1):

I don't have my Mac in front of me currently since I'm at work, but would it be possible to bind an instance of one delegate to a member of the other delegate? This would be similar to binding an NSArrayController to a member of another controller class, for example.

However, depending on what the delegate classes are doing, if the tasks are similar I would probably just combine them into once class. That would eliminate the problem altogether.